# The use of "to attain" with reference to age

Tags: word-usage

When I use the word "attain" for "reaching a particular age" in order to sound formal , does it sound natural?

> Surveys reveal some of the teenagers develop the habit of smoking
>   before they attain the age of legal smoking, which is 16.

or

> Surveys reveal some of the teenagers develop the habit of smoking
>   before they attain the age of 16, which is legal age to start smoking.

Answer (score 1):

***[To attain](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/attain)*** referring  to age suggests a level you have finally reached after much effort or time. It is mainly used in  formal contexts.

> - to come to or arrive at, especially after some labor or tedium;reach:
>
>   - *to attain the age of 96; to attain the mountain peak.*

Dictionary.com

You can see usage examples here [Ngrm](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=attain%20the%20age%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cattain%20the%20age%20of%3B%2Cc0).

From [The Law of Succession](https://books.google.it/books?id=6AaDAAAAIAAJ&q=%22attain%20the%20age%20of%22&dq=%22attain%20the%20age%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE6Y3z7ozSAhUSGhQKHTd_CcI4ChDoAQhEMAk):

> - A fund is bequeathed to A for his life and after his death to B for his lite ; and after B's death to such of the ***sons of B as shall first attain the age of 25.***  A and B survive the testator. Here the son of B who shall first attain the age of 25 may be a son ...